# Paste values instead of formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

What I want to do is to copy the value in cell I6 in Sheet1 and paste it in a specific row (based on match) in Sheet2. However, my current code pastes the formula instead of the value:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    rowNum = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Cells(6, 6), Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A6:A100"), 0)
    Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(7, 9).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(rowNum + 5, 9)
End Sub
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the last line with this:

```
Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(rowNum + 5, 9) = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(7, 9).Value
```